# the procedure entry point _crtCreateSymbolicLinkW couldnot be located

Tags: windows, dll, operating-system, wamp, wampserver

On starting `WAMP` I'm getting this error: the procedure entry point _crtCreateSymbolicLinkW couldnot be located in the dynamic link library MSVCR110.dll

Comment: Is there a programming-related question hidden in there?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: wamp is developer software, so on-topic under the "software tools commonly used by programmers" clause.

Comment: Sounds like you've got a wrong DLL version, perhaps you need to reinstall wamp?

Comment: This is a problem on XP, not initially supported by VS2012.  The DLL was overwritten by an installer of another program, it put an old version of the DLL on the machine.  Standard DLL Hell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BIT NOTE: WAMPServer2.5 will not run on Windows XP, as this dll `MSVCR110.dll` cannot be installed on XP.

Please make sure you have the latest version of all of these Microsoft C/C++ Redistributable runtime libraries. You dont need the whole compiler, just these C/C++ runtime libraries.

**FOR WAMPServer 32bit**

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5582)

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=8328)

**If you are using WampServer 2.4 or 2.5 32bit and therefore Apache 2.4.x**

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 is required](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30679)  And select vcredist_x86.exe

**FOR WAMPServer 64bit**

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5582)

```
Yes you need the x86 Package regardless as
wampmanager is a 32bit exe even on a 64 bit install
```

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15336)

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13523)

**If you are using WampServer 2.4 64bit**

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30679)  And select vcredist_x64.exe

**Warning:** The naming convention used for the redist install files is a bit confusing, so download one, install it, then download the next and install it.... otherwwise you will get confused.

Once they are installed your 'Programs and Features' should look something like this :-

32bit systems
[image: 32bit system]

64bit systems
[image: 64bit system]

The `Unable to load dll issue` is simply fixed by getting WAMPServer to refresh the SYMLINKS in the ...\apache2.4.9\bin folder

Do this as follows using the Wampmanager menus :-

```
left click wampmanager -> Apache -> Version
and click on the version number, probably 2.4.9
```

It takes a couple of second to complete and you wont notice anything going on, but the php_intl error should be solved.

Comment: Why MSVCR110.dll cannot be installed on XP?

Comment: This is controlled by Microsoft and nothing to do with WAMPServer/Apache etc. Remember XP is dead, it had a VERY LONG LIFE but now its time to upgrade. The good news is that Microsoft seem to be saying they will be giving away W10 as a FREE upgrade to any previous version of windows, for the first year of W10's life.

Comment: @Pacerier Yup it is. That does not change the fact that it is to all intents and purposes DEAD. I am sure there are some people still using Win98, but that is also dead.

Comment: No, just look at the stats at http://gs.statcounter.com/#desktop-os-ww-monthly-201504-201504-bar , You can't find any Win98. But XP is third.  **Third** dude.

Comment: Microsoft created this limitiation, not me, if XP is missing something needed to install the 2012 runtime talk to microsoft. [This seems to  say MS have allowed VS 2012 to target XP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/10/08/windows-xp-targeting-with-c-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx). Now all you need to do is ask the Apache Group to make use of it, **if thats possible** But why would they bother. As we are all aware one of the major drawbacks with windows is there decision to make it **always backward compatible** which means they have to carry around megabytes of _old code bloat_ already